# publish application settings (not documents) in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a couple settings which I need in my application. Now I want to make a couple of them available on the client. So I did:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.publish('settings', function () {
        return {
           isAuth: false
        }
});
```

And I've a subscription like

```
Meteor.subscribe('settings');
```

This doesn't work at all, somehow I have the feeling this only works for Collections. So the question is how can I get these settings in the client. Also, these settings are needed to render stuff, so I need this data during init!

Comment: `isAuth` seems more like session variable than actual settings... You know that everything out of `/server` and `/client` are by default shared by both ?

Comment: yes I know, but the value stored in `isAuth` comes from `Meteor.settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's okay to put those configuration settings in code, then just do what Marco says.

If you want to specify them in a JSON configuration file, use [`Meteor.settings`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_settings) - anything in the `public` field in the configuration file is available on the client in `Meteor.settings.public`.

It is possible to do this with publish/subscribe, but it's probably overkill:

```js
// On the server
Meteor.publish("applicationSettings", function () {
  this.added("settings", "arbitrary_string", {isAuth: true});
  this.ready();
});

// On the client
Settings = new Meteor.Collection("settings"); // ONLY on the client
Meteor.subscribe("applicationSettings");
// after subscription is ready,
// Settings.findOne() returns {_id: "arbitrary_string", isAuth: true}
```

Answer (score 3):

Save the settings in a shared js file 
/shared/const.js:

```
     Global.settings = {
        'Something'
     };
```

The publish/subscribe system is only ment to be used for collections.

Although on a side note isAuth doesn't really sound like a setting but a session variable./

Comment: `isAuth` in my case means if the application was started with authentication enabled :) However, your answer doesn't seem to work, because I do something like this: `App.isAuth = Meteor.settings.authenticate;`. I see `App` on the client, but without the `isAuth`. I guess it has to do with the fact that `Meteor.settings` is only available on the server

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Then you should use the meteor settings and put it in the public section. See user3374348's answer